# MikroOrm: Get list of schemas

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm

How can i retrieve a list of all the schemas of a mikro-orm.config.js DB Connection?

I tried

```
const publicOrm = await MikroORM.init(MikroOrmOptions);
const result = await publicOrm
  .getSchemaGenerator()
  .execute('select schema_name from information_schema.schemata;');
```

But 'result' always undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `execute` method on `SchemaGenerator` does not return anything, as its meant for schema commands and not select queries. You can use `execute` method on the driver or even use a QB:

```
const orm = await MikroORM.init(...);
const driver = orm.em.getDriver();
const result = driver.execute('select schema_name from information_schema.schemata');
```

Or even better, you can use `SchemaHelper.getNamespaces()` method that will give you a list of existing schemas directly:

```
const orm = await MikroORM.init(...);
const platform = orm.em.getPlatform();
const result = await platform.getSchemaHelper()!.getNamespaces();
```

(this is what gets used in the schema generator database reflection, it will also automatically ignore system schemas prefixed with `pg_` and `crdb_`, and information schema)